# Handle recurring param in react router path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

react-router-dom 4.3.1

Given a route like

```
<Route path=":normalParam/:repeatingParam+" component={MyComponent} />
```

Is `:repeatingParam+` the best way to handle a param that will repeat many times?

Incase you're wondering why, I'm attempting to model something like a taxonomy tree that will have unknown levels of depth, leading to a url path like

`:normalParam/10/23/344/555/64/3333/22222....`

where each subsequent param is like a child of the previous

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths)? It might help you.

Comment: @thirtydot I was really hoping to avoid that kind of thing, its a workable solution though. Thanks